# How to use angular2 datepipe in input

Tags: angular

I have a date string coming from my server as below. :

`1992-05-26T18:30:00Z`

I am trying to format this to DD/MM/YYYY format using date pipe and bind it to my input ngModel.

```
var userdate:any = new Date(data.draftData.accountHolder.dateOfBirth);
this.setDob = userdate | date:'MM/DD/YYYY';
```

It throws me an error :

> ReferenceError: date is not defined

My HTML is as follows

```
<md-input placeholder="Date of birth" value="mm/dd/yy" [(ngModel)]="setDob"></md-input>
```

Can someone point what am I missing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pipes are supposed to be used in the template, not in code.

```
<div>{{userdate | date:'MM/DD/YYYY'}}</div>
```

You can use it in code as well though, like

```
var userdate:any = new Date(data.draftData.accountHolder.dateOfBirth);
var datePipe = new DatePipe();
this.setDob = datePipe.transform(userdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Comment: Returns value "05" for the above mentioned date string. Why is that?

Comment: @Prashanth Use 'MM/dd/yyyy' https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/common/test/pipes/date_pipe_spec.ts#L59

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-class.html `d` is for `day` instead of `D`. Thanks @yurzui.

Comment: Thanks @yurzui and @ Günter Zöchbauer, works as required.

Comment: "var datePipe = new DatePipe()" this will not work... change to  "var datePipe = new DatePipe('en-US')"

Answer (score 0):

You can use "separated data binding" like as instead of "two-way data-binding".

In common case we use `[(ngModel)]="setDob"`, but you cannot use pipes in this case.
The "separated data binding" will help us to use pipes, for example:

`<input [ngModel]="setDob | somePipeMethod" (ngModelChange)="setDob=$event" />`

Answer (score -1):

```
let datepipe = new DatePipe('en-US');
let date = new Date(data.draftData.accountHolder.dateOfBirth);
let formattedDate = this.datepipe.transform(date,"MM/dd/y HH:MM");
```

Comment: Code only answers might solve the issue, but some explanation of how it solves the problem would help in learning to understand how to solve future problems.